# Knockout validatedObservable data-bind not working as expected

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm trying to data-bind to a validatedObservable but the control does not seem updatable as other knockout observables.

Fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/EricHerlitz/x7UUg/

Short explanation

```
// variable with the data bound observable
that.validationErrors = ko.validatedObservable();

// Elements to validate
var validationGroup = {
    email1: that.email1,
    firstName: that.firstName
};

// Trying to use the validatedObservable in a normal knockout way doesn't work
that.validationErrors(validationGroup);

// This will fill the variable with the observable result but as usual when performing this pattern the viewmodel must be rebound.
that.validationErrors = ko.validatedObservable(validationGroup);
```

Source

```
<h3>Registrering</h3>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Email1">E-postadress</label>
    <input data-bind="value: email1" id="Email1" class="form-control" placeholder="E-postadress (du kommer få lösenords-länk skickad hit)" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Firstname">Förnamn</label>
    <input data-bind="value: firstName" id="Firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="Förnamn" />
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: registerClick">Registrera</button>

<div class="alert alert-danger" data-bind="visible: !validationErrors.isValid()">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4>There be dragons!</h4>
    <div data-bind="foreach: validationErrors.errors">
        <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js

```
var GK = GK || {};
GK.VM = GK.VM || {};

GK.VM.Member = function (template) {
    /*** Private variables ***/
    var that = this;

    /*** Public variables ***/
    that.validationErrors = ko.validatedObservable();

    // variables with validation, https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation
    that.email1 = ko.observable().extend({
        required: { params: true, message: "missingEmail" },
        pattern: { params: /^([\d\w-\.]+@([\d\w-]+\.)+[\w]{2,4})?$/, message: "wrongEmailFormat" }
    });
    that.firstName = ko.observable().extend({
        required: { params: true, message: "missingFirstName" }
    });

    that.registerClick = function () {

        // Elements to validate
        var validationGroup = {
            email1: that.email1,
            firstName: that.firstName
        };

        // This would be ideal but doesn't work
        //that.validationErrors(validationGroup);
        //console.log(that.validationErrors.errors()); // does not contain any erros

        // This will destroy the data-bind but register the validatedObservable
        // Requires rebinding of the control :(
        that.validationErrors = ko.validatedObservable(validationGroup);
        console.log(that.validationErrors.errors()); // contains errors
    };
};

var viewModel = new GK.VM.Member();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Any advice how to deal with this? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to "update" your `validatedObservable`? Do you want to validate different parts of your model on different actions?

Comment: No, but the validation should trigger on the that.registerClick

Comment: In this case and because you are anyway creating a separate validation area I would initialize the `validationErrors` at begining and create a `showErrorMessages` observable and use that to show hide the errors: http://jsfiddle.net/jJ9JS/1/

Comment: @nemesv That will do, thank you for the idea. Please post that as an answer and I'll mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current you cannot update a `validatedObservable` after it has been created without re-creating it completely.

However if you don't need this dynamic aspect of adding removing properties to it but you just need to show the collected validation messages based on criteria (when the `registerClick` is called) then there are alternative solutions.

One solution would be to create the `validatedObservable` normally:

```
that.validationErrors = ko.validatedObservable({
    email1: that.email1,
    firstName: that.firstName
});
```

Then add a new observable:

```
that.showErrorMessages = ko.observable();
```

and use that in the UI

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" 
    data-bind="visible: showErrorMessages() && !validationErrors.isValid()">
```

and in the `registerClick` to toggle when the validation messages should be shown:

```
that.registerClick = function () {
    that.showErrorMessages(true);
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jJ9JS/1/).